# std::arrayの要素数を変数で指定する方法

Tags: c++

C++で

```
template <class Type> class Vector
  std::array<Type, dim> value;

public:
  ......
};
```

というテンプレートクラスを作りたいのですが、std::arrayの引数dimを外から指定する方法はありますか？

```
Vector(double, 4) my_vector;
```

というような変数宣言ができるようにしたいのですが……

訂正

```
Vector(double, 4) my_vector; → Vector<double, 4> my_vector;
```

Comment: BLUEPIXYさんの方法できちんと実行できたのですが、sayuriさんの話も聞いたことがあります。これはどういうことでしょうか……？

Comment: 4 が定数値だからでは？（コンパイル時に決定している）
以下のように変数を指定することはできない（実行時に値が決まる）。
    int count = getCount();    Vector(double, count) my_vector;

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 3, accepted):

テンプレート引数に以下の様に定数を指定できます。

```
template <class Type, size_t dim>
class Vector {
  std::array<Type, dim> value;
…

Vector<double, 4> my_vector;
```

Answer (score 6):

`std::array`は固定長配列でその長さはコンパイル時に決まっている必要があります。変数で指定したい場合は`std::vector`など他のクラスを使うことになります。

---

> BLUEPIXYさんの方法できちんと実行できたのですが、sayuriさんの話も聞いたことがあります。これはどういうことでしょうか……？

質問文がいろいろと間違っていることにも原因がありそうです。

> Vector(double, 4) my_vector;

はそもそも構文が間違っていて、

```
// テンプレート引数
Vector<double, 4> my_vector;

// コンストラクター引数
Vector<double> my_vector(4);
```

のどちらかです。質問タイトルも

> std::arrayの要素数を変数で指定する方法

`テンプレート引数`のことであれば`変数`という表現は不適切です。
BLUEPIXYさんの方法で実行できているのであればその方がいいですが、先に書いたように変数で指定し実行時に決定される方法には使えません。

Comment: すみません、転記ミスです。実際のコードではVector<double, 4>としていました。テンプレート引数は変数とは違うのですね。